# KOMA letter: fit longer address / change address font size?

Tags: koma-script, fontsize, letters

Using KOMA letter class `scrlttr2`, what is the right way to fit a longer address?

What's the right way to change only the address font size?

Comment: What was the result of the update?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble with my package manager, so this may be the reason your initial suggestion didn't work. Works with the "legacy" answer, though - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Font size**

You can change the font size for the address field by using the  command `\addtokomafont` with the field name and the font declaration as arguments:

```
\addtokomafont{addressee}{\large}  %% or `\small`
```

**Address field**

You change the height and width of the address field by setting two different KOMA-script pseudo length, see page 501–502 in the manual. I cite from the manual:

```
\setplength{toaddrheight}{length }
```

> This pseudo-length defines the height of the address field, including the delivery method. Whether the name and address of the recipient are vertically centred in the address field, taking into account the presence or absence of the delivery method, depends on the addrfield option.

```
\setplength{toaddrwidth}{length }
```

> This pseudo-length defines the width of the address field. The various predefined lco files use different settings according to the different standards for window envelopes. Typical values are between 70mm and 100 mm.

In the preamble of your letter, you add the two commands, for example:

```
\setplength{toaddrheight}{50mm}
\setplength{toaddrwidth}{110mm}
```

You may instead use the command `\addtoplength` to *add* to a length to an existing `plength`:

```
\addtoplength{toaddrwidth}{10mm} 
\addtoplength{toaddrheight}{10mm}
```

which will add 1 cm to the existing height and width.

**IN CASE OF OUTDATED SYSTEM**

If you have an outdated version of KOMA-script you have to use two low level commands *instead* of the two I suggested:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrwidth}{105mm}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{35mm}
\makeatother
```

Here is an MWE (for an updated system), borrowed from the manual and adapted. Instruction for outdated systems is added as commented code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[visualize]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{yellow}}
\setkomafont{measure}{\color{red}\small}
\setkomafont{letter}{\color{green}}
\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtoplength{toaddrwidth}{30mm} 
\addtoplength{toaddrheight}{10mm}
%% If you have a outdated system, comment out (i.e. add a per cent sign)
%% the two lines above and instead use:

%\makeatletter
%\@setplength{toaddrwidth}{105mm}
%\@setplength{toaddrheight}{35mm}
%\makeatother
%% Remove the % from the for lines (not this line)

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Public}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{2 Valley\\
SAMPLEBY\\
ZY32 1XW}
\begin{letter}{%
1 Hillside\\
10 Downside\\
112 Uphill on the Upside of the green River behind the bush
SAMPLESTEAD\\
WEARDSHIRE\\
WX12 3YZ\\
A STRANGE COUNTRY%
}
\opening{Hello,}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{Good bye}
\end{letter}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\renewcommand*{\unitfactor}{10}
\showISOenvelope{DL}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I get an `undefined control sequence. \setplength` error when adding the two commands - any idea where that comes from? Same error when using your MWE.

Comment: I am referring to the MWE you provided. I do have the KOMA letter class, because your MWE works when the two commands are removed.

Comment: It seems that you have a really outdated version of KOMA-script, or use Overleaf, which also have a old an outdated system. See updated answer.

Comment: No Overleaf, but am currently updating the packages; will comment as soon as it is done, thanks!

Comment: I have updated the code with code for font size change. However, since this is a different question, you should have asked a new question.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick and precise responses! I have asked both questions as one because they revolve around the same issue - fitting the address inside the window.